# Where are the account data of a new asp.net mvc web application put?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

If you create a new ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application and run it, you can register new users and logon. But I can not find where does those account data are put. Database? Local files? Or session???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App_Data folder, if you click "Show all files", you'll see a database called ASPNETDB.MDF.  This is where the user login data is stored.  (Double click it to open it in server explorer and you'll see a table called "aspnet_Users")

The file is referenced by the web.config file in you project root - there's a connection string called "ApplicationServices" that points to the database file directly.